# How to use competitive for a group of people?

Tags: comparative-constructions, superlatives

I want to say that 2-3 people are the most competitive, they are part for the same group. In theory "the most" is for a single. I do not know how to say for a group of people or characteristics.

Is that correct if I say: The most competitive soccer players (want to refer that 2-3 of the group are the most competitive.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

“The most” does not have to refer to one person/thing. I use “the most” all the time to refer to multiple subjects.

> They are the most competitive players on the team.

is fine.

Similar sentences include:

> Geometry and algebra are the most common topics on this test.
>
> Ian and Bianca are the most athletic people at this school.

Etc.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you to provide a quick support :)

Answer (score -2):

You say "competitive".  English does not change the spelling of verbs merely because of the number or type of the people who are referred to.  In English, the verb is always the same, except for based on the time which an event has occured or will occur.  This will be past-tense and present tense.  So, these are tenses, not conjugations.  English does not have conjugations.

Also, the following portion of my answer is gramatically incorrect:

"except for based on the time which"

Comment: English absolutely does have conjugations. It's why you say "I run" and "she runs". The change is not dramatic for regular verbs, but it can be for irregular verbs. Look at "to be".